# getAsyncKeyState not recognizing key input

Tags: c++, winapi, input

So I decided that I wanted to write a little keylogger tonight, just to learn about getAsyncKeyState.  I'm trying to get my log to write to a file but the file's contents either show up blank or throw a random memory address at me (0x28fef0 before).  I've heard that getAsyncKeyState doesn't function well with Windows 7 x64, is it true?

This is pretty aggravating, I was hoping to actually be able to get this running tonight.

```
    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(20);
        for(DWORD_PTR key = 8; key <= 190; key++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == HC_ACTION)
                checkKey(key);
        }
    }
```

Function definition

```
void checkKey(DWORD_PTR key)
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("log.txt");

        if (key==8)
            out << "[del]";
        if (key==13)
            out << "n";
        if (key==32)
            out << " ";
        if (key==VK_CAPITAL)
            out << "[CAPS]";
        if (key==VK_TAB)
            out << "[TAB]";
        if (key==VK_SHIFT)
            out << "[SHIFT]";
        if (key==VK_CONTROL)
            out << "[CTRL]";
        if (key==VK_PAUSE)
            out << "[PAUSE]";
        if (key==VK_ESCAPE)
            out << "[ESC]";
        if (key==VK_END)
            out << "[END]";
        if (key==VK_HOME)
            out << "[HOME]";
        if (key==VK_LEFT)
            out << "[LEFT]";
        if (key==VK_UP)
            out << "[UP]";
        if (key==VK_RIGHT)
            out << "[RIGHT]";
        if (key==VK_DOWN)
            out << "[DOWN]";
        if (key==VK_SNAPSHOT)
            out << "[PRINT]";
        if (key==VK_NUMLOCK)
            out << "[NUM LOCK]";
        if (key==190 || key==110)
            out << ".";
        if (key >=96 && key <= 105)
        {
            key -= 48;
            out << &key; // had ampersand
        }
        if (key >=48 && key <= 59)
            out << &key; // amp'd
        if (key !=VK_LBUTTON || key !=VK_RBUTTON)
        {
            if (key >=65 && key <=90)
            {
                if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL))
                out << &key; // amp;d
            else
            {
                key = key +32;
                out << &key; // amp'd
            }
        }
        }
}
```

I'm seriously stumped by this issue and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Why would a function like this work differently on a 64 bit system?  Considering it's the only box I've got I can't run it on a 32 bit to check whether or not it's an isolated issue.  Because I'm assuming that it's related to getAsyncKeyState and not my code (which compiles and creates a blank log file) I only included those two code snippets.

Comment: If you want to get the state of the entire keyboard (i.e. all the keys), don't make multiple calls to `GetAsyncKeyState`. Instead, call `GetKeyboardState`. That's going to perform much better. But for a key logger, you want to use a keyboard hook or listen for `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_KEYDOWN`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the function incorrectly. Reading the documentation before requesting help is usually a good idea...

I'll just quote MSDN here:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you
>   should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the
>   Remarks.

That last part also means it's completely useless for a key logger.

PS: Consider using `GetKeyNameText` for translating virtual key codes into meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll be sure to doublecheck MSDN from now on, I must've overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly you don't want to be using GetAsyncKeyState if you are writing a key logger;  GetAsyncKeyState gets the state of the key at the immediate moment you call the function. You need to be listening in on the Windows messages, for things like WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, or depending on the purpose of the logger WM_CHAR, WM_UNICHAR etc...

Answer (score 1):

For monitoring input, something like a keyboard hook is probably the way to go (look up SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD_LL on MSDN).

As noted elsewhere, you're not using GetAsyncKeyState correctly here.

As for why you're seeing an address appear:

```
out << &key; // amp'd
```

This is several places in your code: key is a DWORD_PTR, so &key is a pointer - this is likely where the addresses are coming from.